# Mysql - Query para retornar do dia 01 ao dia corrente do mês

Tags: mysql

alguém consegue me dar uma ajuda?

Preciso de uma query que retorne por exemplo, do dia 01/11 até o dia de hoje, 22/11. Amanhã, retorne do 01, até dia 23. No inicio do mês, preciso por exemplo que retorne do 01, até o dia 2, supondo que o dia corrente é o dia 02. Não tenho ideia como fazer isso.

Alguém conseguiria ajudar?

Obrigado.

Comment: Bom, dia 1 sempre é dia 1, independente do mês. Não bastaria você buscar pelo dia 1 do mês corrente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS DATA_INICIAL, STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS DATA_FINAL
```

Explanação:

- NOW() -> Data/hora atual
- DATE_FORMAT -> Converte uma data para string no formato especificado
- CONCAT -> Concatenação de textos. No caso, concatenamos o ano + mês
  com "01" para ter o primeiro dia do mês.
- STR_TO_DATE -> Converte uma string para data

Mais detalhes sobre cada uma das funções, vc encontra na documentação neste [link](https://dev.mysql.com/).

Pode-se usar tanto para listar como fiz no exemplo acima quanto na cláusula where...

Comment: Orra Ricardo, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Vou olhar a documentação e agora já tenho como me virar aqui. 

Valeu mesmo.